# QField using QGIS Authentication database?

Tags: qgis, postgis, qfield

I run a postgres database with postgis on an external server.
To secure the connection to the database i have self singed certificates set up.
I added the certificates in QGIS and saved them together with the login credentials to the postgres database in the QGIS Authentification database.
For the also on the external server running QGIS-server to be able to connect to the database, i was able to specify enviroment-parameters in the server config pointing to the qgis-auth.db and the masterpassword for the qgis-auth.db safed as .txt.
As described here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/auth_system/auth_overview.html

I would also like to use QField and work directly on the postgis Layer with a secure connetction.

Is it possible to use the qgis-auth.db in QField similar to how its done with QGIS-server?

Answer (score 1):

This is not (yet) possible.

But you could use a service connection file instead:
Define Postgresql services in a pg_service.conf file and use it on your mobile device by placing it directly in a directory named QField in the main folder of the internal storage.

Btw. feel free to create feature requests on https://qfield.org/issues/